# title attribute in pretty photo

Tags: jquery, html

I used the following pretty photo code in my site:

```
     <ul class="gallery clearfix">
            <li><a href="images/fullscreen/2.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto"     title="&lt;a href=&#x27;http://www.google.ca&#x27; target=&#x27;_blank&#x27; &gt;This will    open Google.com in a new window&lt;/a&gt;"><img src="images/thumbnails/t_2.jpg" width="60"   height="60" alt="Picture alone 1" /></a></li>
        </ul>
```

However when I hover the image, on the web page it shows the content in the title attributte which is

```
      <a href="http//www.google.ca" target="_blank" />This will open Google.com in a new window</a>
```

How can I get rid of that content when I hover the picture, but I still want to maintain it in my code just don't want to see it when hovering the picture, is there a way to do that, I don't mind to use php, jquery, javascript there all kind of techniques to solve the problem. any one could help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Any particular reason why you want the title in your code?

Comment: because I want the link to dispay underneath the pretty phote, at the moment i thinks that's the only way, do you know if there is another way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".gallery.clearfix a").each(function(){
    $(this).data("title",this.title);
}).hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("title","");
},function(){
    $(this).attr("title",$(this).data("title"));
}).mousedown(function(){
    $(this).attr("title",$(this).data("title"));
});
```

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/yAa7L/

This will work for clearing it and reseting it... no idea why this is necessary however.

Comment: @josephy, sorry, josephy, it works fine, but the google link is gone, how can I still maintain the google link, thanks!

Comment: @smith how is it gone? could you show on a jsfiddle or demo site?

Comment: sorry, it would be difficult, I am not sure if I can show picture on that site, it just when I hover the picture, the hover content is gone, but when I click to see the picture, the link underneath it is gone, I don't want it gone, I want the link still there, howcan I do that, thanks!

Comment: @smith I've amended my code.  See if that works.  I had to go to the plugin's sight and monkey with my js console there. :P

Comment: This time works, thanks for spend time for helping me solve this vital problem, it would be nice if I know your eamil or other contacts so that in future when I have problem I can directly ask you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a better solution would be to edit source code of PrettyPhoto and make it use data-title attribute instead of title. For version 3.1.5 you can do this by editing line 155 and changing 'title' to 'data-title':

```
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).attr('title')) ? $(n).attr('title') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('title'));
```

So it looks like this afterwards:

```
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).attr('data-title')) ? $(n).attr('data-title') : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('data-title'));
```